# How can I be able to save a tensor flow model which has no variables?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

For example how to save this model: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/input_fn/boston.py

Comment: Does the suggested solution work for you?

Comment: Can you help me out with one more model I am building?

Comment: yes, i can help you

Comment: How can I contact? 
Please take a look at this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801521/how-to-predict-the-output-in-a-tensorflow-model

Comment: I am new to stack overflow, i don't know how one would contact people personally.

Comment: Take a look at question I mentioned above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147814/discussion-between-prashant-shubham-and-vijay-m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is saved in the `model_dir` when you were calling:

```
regressor = tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor(feature_columns=feature_cols,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 10],
                                        model_dir="/tmp/boston_model")
```

Now during inference you call the above and then the `regressor.predict()` function with the new input.