# How to predict the output in a tensorflow model?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am building a tensorflow model which should give output as 0 or 1 in case of some parameters or features being exceeded. I have the training data set, and I have trained the model but the given a set of data the predictions are wrong. The accuracy of the model is being given as 94% still, the predictions are wrong. 
Thanks in advance for help.
Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import os
import itertools
import tempfile
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

#tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

BASE_DIRECTORY =  r"C:\Users\pshubham\Documents\IoT\liota-edge_intelligence\edge_intelligence_models"
MODEL_BASE_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(BASE_DIRECTORY, 'saved-windmill-model')
TEMP_MODEL_PATH = tempfile.mkdtemp(dir=MODEL_BASE_DIRECTORY)
TRAINING_FILE = os.path.join(BASE_DIRECTORY, 'windmill-train-data.csv')
TESTING_FILE = os.path.join(BASE_DIRECTORY, 'windmill-test-data.csv')
PREDICT_FILE = os.path.join(BASE_DIRECTORY, 'windmill-predict-data.csv')

COLUMNS = ["Timestamp", "windmill.RPM", "windmill.Vibration", "windmill.AmbientTemperature",
        "windmill.RelativeHumidity", "windmill.TurnOff"]
FEATURES = ["windmill.RPM", "windmill.Vibration"]
LABEL = "windmill.TurnOff"

def input_fn(train_data_set):
    features = {k: tf.constant(train_data_set[k].values) for k in FEATURES}
    label = tf.constant(train_data_set[LABEL].values)
    return features, label

def build_model():
    train = pd.read_csv(TRAINING_FILE, names=COLUMNS, skipinitialspace = True, skiprows=1)

    train['type']='Train' #A flag for train data set

    feature_cols = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(k)
                for k in FEATURES]
    optimizer = tf.train.FtrlOptimizer(
        learning_rate=0.1,
        l1_regularization_strength=1.0,
        l2_regularization_strength=1.0)

    e = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_cols, optimizer=optimizer, model_dir=TEMP_MODEL_PATH)

    e.fit(input_fn=lambda:input_fn(train), steps=20)
    return e 

def freezeGraph(model_folder, save_folder):
    checkpoint = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(model_folder)
    input_checkpoint = checkpoint.model_checkpoint_path

    output_graph_filepath = os.path.join(save_folder,"frozen_model.pb")

    output_node_names = [
    "linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/zeros_like",
    "linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/concat/axis",
    "linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/concat",
    "linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/logistic",
    "linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/probabilities",
    "linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/classes/dimension",
    "linear/binary_logistic_head/predictions/classes"]

    clear_devices = True

    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(input_checkpoint + '.meta', clear_devices=clear_devices)
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_graph_def = graph.as_graph_def()

    # We start a session and restore the graph weights
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, input_checkpoint)

        # We use a built-in TF helper to export variables to constants
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
            sess, # The session is used to retrieve the weights
            input_graph_def, # The graph_def is used to retrieve the nodes 
            output_node_names # The output node names are used to select the useful nodes
        ) 

        # Finally we serialize and dump the output graph to the filesystem
        with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph_filepath, "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
        print("%d ops in the final graph." % len(output_graph_def.node))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    mymodel = build_model()

    test = pd.read_csv(TESTING_FILE, names=COLUMNS, skipinitialspace = True, skiprows=1)
    predict = pd.read_csv(PREDICT_FILE, names=COLUMNS, skipinitialspace = True, skiprows=1)

    test['type']='Test'
    predict['type']='Predict'

    freezeGraph(TEMP_MODEL_PATH, MODEL_BASE_DIRECTORY)    


    ev = mymodel.evaluate(input_fn=lambda:input_fn(test), steps=1)

    loss_score = ev["loss"]

    print("Loss: {0:f}".format(loss_score))

    y = mymodel.predict(input_fn=lambda:input_fn(predict))

    predictions= list(itertools.islice(y,6))
    print("Predictions: {}".format(str(predictions)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these changes for the network to train better:

1. Scale your inputs: your csv file inputs are not scaled. You can use something like sklearn `StandardScaler` to normalize your inputs
2. You are not training enough. I see the number of steps (20) is way low. Try atleast 10000 and train it using Adam optimizer for faster convergence: 
   `optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)`

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you split your training data to test your model on unseen data. If this is true, the 94% is only on your training data and your model has overfitted. You should test your accuracy on the 'validation set' (around 20% of your input data is usually representative enough, depending on your amount of data, of course) after each epoch and stop when the training accuracy keeps increasing and the validation accuracy decresing.

#### Edit after your comment

In case you did split the data, did you do it in a stratified way? Can you plot a distribution of your the classes in all the sets? These should be similar to each other. Take a look at [StratifiedShuffleSplit](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html) from sklearn.

Comment: I have split it to test it on unseen data. The data is here: https://github.com/lucifercr07/liota/blob/edge_intelligence/edge_intelligence_models/windmill-data.csv
Out of this I divided 200 for the train, 100 for the testing and rest for prediction, which was fed into the model.